How much money does the de minimis rule save on small orders?
There is a certain amount of controversy about some online retailers use of the de minimis rule to avoid tax.  I have not found anywhere that specifies how much this tax would be.  An example article is Time: The Tax Loophole That Helps Temu and Shein Keep Prices So Low:

several Congresspeople have drafted legislation that aims to reduce one of the main trading advantages Temu and Shein have: a trade rule known as de minimis that allows them to ship packages without paying duty and certain taxes as long as shipments are under the value of $800. “It is a huge loophole that particularly enables these two companies to send a gusher of product to the U.S and undercut American businesses that are literally being driven out of business by this competition,” Congressman Earl Blumenauer (D., Ore.) tells TIME.

Is it easy to say how much "duty and certain taxes" would be on a small (say 20 pound, dollar or euro) package of consumer goods?
Answers for any jurisdiction would be interesting, most relevant would be the US and EU for their size and the UK as I live there.  I am sure this also saves a significant amount of paperwork, but I am particularly interested in the money.

The US tariff schedule varies with the commodity and where it comes from:
for example for cotton T-shirts (6109.10.00) the standard tariff is 16.5%, while for man-made fiber T-shirts (6109.90.10) it is 32%.
For goods from China there is a 7.5% supplement to both, while for some other countries there is no tariff.
